# Ruby: What is one-line code to generate x repeated characters?

Tags: ruby

I want a function that generates a number of repeated characters and puts in a string. For example,

```
> n = 6
> generate_repeated_str(n,'9')
"999999"
```

How do I write a one-line code to do that in Ruby?

EDIT:
Since this is not a rails question, the title was updated and 'Rails' was removed.

Comment: Have you tried `'9' * 6`?

Comment: This is not a rails question, title is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def generate_repeated_str(n, char)
  char * n
end
```

or just

```
n = 6
'9' * n
=> '999999'
```